# How to configure checkbox input in Vue 3 to check/uncheck when clicking image

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox, vuejs3, v-model

I am setting up a div container to include both an image and an input element with type `checkbox`. The checkbox input includes a click handler that passes a value as an argument to some function. The input also includes a :value binding, which is passed to an array called `checkBoxArray`. Finally, the input uses `v-model=checkBoxArray` to check when the array contains a value. If the array contains a value, then the checkbox will be checked. I also wish to enable clicking on an image next to the checkbox, in order to also check and uncheck the checkbox. However, simply adding the click handler to the image is not enough. How can I go about enabling a click handler on the image element to also check and uncheck a box?

Here is my code so far:

```
          <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
            <span class="flex-1 flex">
              <span class="flex flex-col mr-4 mt-16">
                <input v-model="checkBoxArray" :value="item.id" @click="someFunction(item.id)" type="checkbox" class="h-5 w-5" />
              </span>
              <span class="flex flex-col">
                <img @click="someFunction(item.id)" class="h-full w-full" :src="item.image_url" alt="" />
              </span>
            </span>
          </div>
```

```
const checkBoxArray = ref([])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly try like following snippet:

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const checkBoxArray = ref([])
    const items = [{id: 0, image_url:  'https://picsum.photos/50'}, {id: 1, image_url: 'https://picsum.photos/51'}]
    const someFunction = (id) => {
      checkBoxArray.value[id] = !checkBoxArray.value[id]
      console.log(id)
    }
    return {
      checkBoxArray, items, someFunction
    };
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <span class="flex-1 flex">
      <span class="flex flex-col mr-4 mt-16">
        <input v-model="checkBoxArray[item.id]"  @click="someFunction(item.id)" type="checkbox" class="h-5 w-5" />
      </span>
      <span class="flex flex-col">
        <img @click="someFunction(item.id)" class="h-full w-full" :src="item.image_url" alt="" />
      </span>
    </span>
{{checkBoxArray}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, something along those lines, though ideally I'd like to still use ```:value="item.id"``` and ```v-model="checkBoxArray"``` instead of ```v-model="checkBoxArray[item.id]"```

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 hey mate `v-model` is the same as `:value` and `@input` , take a look [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html) pls

Comment: I think what I had in mind was for the img element to also have something like ```:value="item.id"``` and ```@click="selectCategory(item.id)"``` so that item.id is also passed to checkBoxArray when clicking on the image.